# jq parsing with arg filters does not give expected result

Tags: jq

jq parser with --arg with String concatenation does not give proper json output. Input file is 'test.json' and output file is 'final.json'

This is input json file
    test.json
    ---------
            {
              "ParameterKey1":  "",
              "Parameterkey2":  "" 
             }

```
    Tried test.json with 2nd filter 
    jq --arg inp4 "$keypassword" \
                    'if .ParameterKey1 == "<value1>"
                            then . + {"ParameterKey1" : ($input1) }
                    else . end'     | jq --arg inp5 "$value2"  \
                    'if .Parameterkey2 == "<value2>"
                            then . + {"value2" : ($input2) }
                    else . end'  test.json   >  final.json


    Tried test.json with 1st filter
    jq --arg inp4 "$key" \
                    'if .ParameterKey1 == "<value1>"
                            then . + {"ParameterKey1" : ($input1) }
                    else . end'  test.json   | jq --arg inp5 "$value2"  \
                    'if .Parameterkey2 == "<value2>"
                            then . + {"value2" : ($input2) }
                    else . end'     >  final.json


    Tried test.json in both filters
    jq --arg inp4 "$key" \
                    'if .ParameterKey1 == "<value1>"
                            then . + {"ParameterKey1" : ($inp4) }
                    else . end'  test.json   | jq --arg inp5 "$value2"  \
                    'if .Parameterkey2 == "<value2>"
                            then . + {"value2" : ($inp5) }
                    else . end'  test.json   >  final.json

    Expected output: (final.json)
      {
          "ParameterKey1":  "value",
          "Parameterkey2":  "value" 
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to learn a bit about jq before you'll be able to use it effectively.  I'd suggest mastering things bit-by-bit before trying to put everything together.

Let's start with `--arg inp4 "$keypassword"`.  That passes the shell variable to a jq dollar-variable, with the net effect of setting the jq variable $inp4 to the string-value of the shell variable $keypassword.  You can then use `$inp4` as a jq variable, like any other -- so no quotation marks around it.

Another useful thing to know how to use is the `-f` command-line option.  That should save you much time and aggravation.

By the way, when you do finally put everything together, you'll only need one invocation of jq.

Comment: Can you provide the code for single invocation of jq with -f command-line option.

Comment: I believe it needs aggravation even if we use -f command-line option